# How to create a Virtual Audio Source in Pipewire that receives data from the default Audio sink (speaker/headphones?)

Tags: java, audio, audio-source, pipewire

I am creating a program in Java and I need to stream internal audio using a [TargetDataLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/TargetDataLine.html) (audio source). I am trying to use `pw-loopback` to create a virtual audio source that receives data from speakers but I can't get it to work..

I have looked at: [tldr pw-loopback docs](https://tldr.dendron.so/notes/linux.pw-loopback.html) for examples..
I cannot access `pactl` and I would like to implement this using Pipewire only.
What commands can I use to create a pipewire audio source that mirrors a default sink?

I have tried the following commands:
`pw-loopback -m '[FL FR]' --capture-props='media.class=Audio/Source'`

and:

`pw-loopback -m '[FL FR]' --capture-props='media.class=Audio/Sink' --playback-props=media.class=Audio/Source`

I also tried using `pw-link` but only got `failed to link ports: No such file or directory`:

`pw-loopback -m '[FL FR]' --capture-props='media.class=Audio/Sink' -n cliradio-sink &`

`pw-loopback -m '[FL FR]' --capture-props='media.class=Audio/Source' -n cliradio-source &`

`pw-link cliradio-sink:monitor cliradio-source:playback`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: posted an issue here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/issues/3880

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished if the flag `stream.capture.sink=true` is passed into capture-props:

`pw-loopback --capture-props='{ stream.capture.sink=true }' -C alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo -m '[FL FR]' --playback-props='media.class=Audio/Source audio.position=[FL FR]' -n my-virtual-source`